# Show that $\gcd(a + b, a^2 + b^2) = 1$ or $2$ if $\gcd(a, b)=1$

Tags: number-theory

Show that $\gcd(a + b, a^2 + b^2) = 1$ or $2$ if $\gcd(a, b)=1$.

I have absolutely no clue where to start and what to do, please provide complete proof and answer.

Comment: Partial duplicate of [How can I find the possible values that $\gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2)$ can take, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307545/how-can-i-find-the-possible-values-that-gcdab-a2b2-can-take-if-gcda), and exact duplicate of [Show that $\gcd(a + b, a^2 + b^2) = 1\mbox{ or } 2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463190/show-that-gcda-b-a2-b2-1-mbox-or-2?rq=1).

Comment: This question was asked yesterday (as were many others) by a user with a different name. If you are that same user (or even if you aren't), please be aware that many of the questions that were asked yesterday already have answers on this site--in fact, when you ask a question, the site automatically gives a list of suggestions for where you might find an answer to that question, based on the title. It would behoove you to look through that list to see what you can find whenever you post a question.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2)=d$
Then $d \mid a+b$ and $d \mid a^2+b^2$.

$d \mid (a+b)(a+b)-(a-b)(a+b)=2a^2$.

$d \mid (a+b)(a+b)+(a-b)(a+b)=2b^2$

$d \mid (2a^2,2b^2) = 2(a^2,b^2)=2(a,b)^2=2.1=2 \implies d=1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 1):

We use repeatedly the identity $\gcd(x,y)=\gcd(x,y+kx)$ for any integer $k$.

For $k=-(a+b)$, we have $$\gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2)=\gcd(a+b,-2ab)$$

But $\gcd(a,b)=1$ so $\gcd(a,a+b)=1$ and similarly $\gcd(b,a+b)=1$.  Combining, we get $\gcd(ab,a+b)=1$.  Hence $\gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2)=\gcd(a+b,-2)$, which is $1$ or $2$.

Answer (score 0):

We first show that there is no odd prime $p$ that divides both $a+b$ and $a^2+b^2$.

For if $p$ divides both, then $p$ divides $(a+b)^2-(a^2+b^2)$, so $p$ divides $2ab$. Since $p$ is odd, it divides one of $a$ or $b$, say $a$. But then since $p$ divides $a+b$, it must divide $b$. This contradicts the fact that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime.

So the only possible common divisors of $a+b$ and $a^2+b^2$ are powers of $2$. If $a$ is even and $b$ is odd (or the other way) then the greatest common divisor of $a+b$ and $a^2+b^2$ is therefore $1$.

If $a$ and $b$ are both odd, then $a^2+b^2\equiv 2\pmod{8}$, and therefore the highest power of $2$ that divides $a^2+b^2$ is $2^1$. So in that case $\gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2)=2$.